# Is expo push notification tool profitable?

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, push-notification, expo

Currently I have developed a mobile application with react-native/expo. But now I have to perform the task of sending notifications. I have also made a backend in NodeJS to send notifications. But I have doubts about the services to use to send notifications. Can someone explain to me if it is profitable to use the expo push notification tool. Because I understand that firebase is free and can send more notifications per day than the expo tool does. What are the advantages and disadvantages of one over the other.

Thank you very much for your answers

Answer (score 0):

The main disadvantage is that you cannot add your custom icon to the expo notification, this was the main problem that I faced with it.

Check this [link](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/9048)